# Prove that If a < b and c < d then a + c < b + d

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

I'm currently on a calculus book. It starts with inequalities and the rules of it. So there is my question:

1. If **a < b** and **b < c**, then **a < c**.
2. If **c** is any number and **a < b**, then it is also true that **a + c < b + c** and **a - c < b - c**.
3. If **a < b** and **c < d** then **a + c < b + d**.

> Q: Show how Rule 3 for inequalities may be derived from Rules 1 and 2.

I understant proofs when somebody do it on a book or video but I can't do it and visualize it by myself. Is there a technique of it?